# Linear regression over months

Tags: powerbi, dax, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a linear regression measure that can be used over months instead of date. However there is something with my table variables that doesn't work and I don't know why.

I have this measure `BwiTable[BWi]` that I display in a line graph. It is a measure that varies over time. It can be displayed with dates on the X-axis, but it makes much more sense to display one value per month so that is what I want to do. Displaying the `BwiTable[BWi]` measure over year and month works just like expected. Since I'm interested in visualize the trend, I want to create a linear regression measure to be shown in the same graph, using the LINESTX DAX function.

I've done a linear regression measure that works just fine over dates, but as said earlier **it needs to work over months**. Since months aren't continuous, I figured I need to add some code for that, so I create X-values `0,1,2,3,4,...` etc over the period I'm interested in. The period is specified with a date slider.
Here's my current code with some debug code included.
The `SelectedDateTable`, `T1`, `Test` and `R` are just for debugging purposes. What I want to return in the end is `y`.

```
BWi (Linear regr. month) = 
    VAR MinAccmonth = 
        MINX(
            ALLSELECTED(PQDateTable), 
            [accountmonth] 
        )
    VAR MaxAccmonth = 
        MAXX(
            ALLSELECTED(PQDateTable), 
            [accountmonth] 
        )
    VAR SelectedDateTable = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        FILTER(
            ALL (PQDateTable[accountmonth]), //,
            PQDateTable[accountmonth] >= MinAccmonth && PQDateTable[accountmonth] <= MaxAccmonth
        ),
        "Acc", PQDateTable[accountmonth],
        "Y", BwiTable[BWi]
    )
    VAR T1 = DISTINCT(SelectedDateTable)    
    

    VAR Known =
        FILTER (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER(
                    ALL(PQDateTable[accountmonth]), 
                    PQDateTable[accountmonth] >= MinAccmonth && PQDateTable[accountmonth] <= MaxAccmonth
                ),
                "Accmonth", PQDateTable[accountmonth],
                "Known[Y]", BwiTable[BWi]
            ),
//            AND (
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Accmonth] ) )//,
//                NOT ( ISBLANK ( Known[Y] ) )
//            )
 
        )

    VAR MinYear = QUOTIENT(MinAccmonth, 100)
    VAR MinMonth = MOD(MinAccmonth, 100)
    
    VAR Known2 = ADDCOLUMNS(
        Known,
        "Known[X]",
        VAR CurrYear = QUOTIENT([Accmonth], 100)
        VAR CurrMonth = MOD([Accmonth], 100)
        RETURN (CurrYear-MinYear)*12 + (CurrMonth-MinMonth)
    ) 
    
    VAR Line = 
        LINESTX(
            Known2,
            Known[Y],
            Known[X]
        )

    // y = kx + m
    VAR k = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Slope", [Slope1])
    VAR m = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Int", [Intercept])
    VAR AM = MIN(PQDateTable[accountmonth])  // Get accountmonth in current filter context
    VAR AMY = QUOTIENT(AM, 100)
    VAR AMM = MOD(AM, 100)
    VAR x = (AMY-MinYear)*12 + (AMM-MinMonth)
    VAR y = k*x+m

 VAR Test = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER(
            Known2,
            Known[X] = 7
        ),
        "Test", Known[Y]
    )
VAR R = COUNTROWS(Known) //Known2)
    RETURN Test
```

What I've figured out so far is that for some reason, when `Known` is calculated, the `BwiTable[BWi]` measure only returns a value for the month that the visual is currently calculating a value for.

E.g: when the visual is calculating for Febuary 2023, the `Known` table only contains one `BwiTable[BWi]`-value, which then is for that specific month. But the idea with the `Known` table is that it should contain `BwiTable[BWi]`-values for all months in the selected period, independent on which month the visual is currently working on, and thus be constant over the period so a linear regresion can be calculated. What is happening now is that the Linear regression table is different for each month the visual calculates it for since there is only one value in the `Known` and thus `Known2` tables. The slope becomees zero(0) and the intercept becomes the same as the one `BwiTable[BWi]`-measure that is calculated since there is only one value in the table that is used as an input to the LINESTX function.
I don't understand why only one `BwiTable[BWi]` value is calculated since `SELECTCOLUMNS`, as far as I understand, works in a row context. I have copied and created the `Known`, `Known2` and `Line` tables as a calculated table and that works just fine. I've also tried it in DAX studio and there also it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't work as a measure???

I'm quite new to PowerBI and databases so there might be something very fundamental with filter context or simular that I'm missing. Can someone please help me and clarify?

Comment: why not export your data and then apply sklearn linear regressor to the data?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to be able to get a continuous value for a year/month pair. You can do that by adding a calculated column to your table with the following formula:

```
MonthCode = (YEAR(PQDateTable[Date]) - 1900) * 12 + MONTH(PQDateTable[Date]) - 1
```

And if you don't have it already, add a column for the Year Month, and sort it by `MonthCode`

```
MonthText = FORMAT(PQDateTable[Date], "MMMM YY")
```

Then your linear regression per month needs to take into account the new column, so:

```
monthR = 
VAR Known = FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALLSELECTED ('PQDateTable'),
        'PQDateTable'[MonthCode],
        "bwi", SUM(tbl[bwi])
        ), NOT(ISBLANK([bwi])))
    VAR Line = 
        LINESTX(
            Known,
            [bwi],
            'PQDateTable'[MonthCode]
        )

    // y = kx + m
    VAR k = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Slope", [Slope1])
    VAR m = SELECTCOLUMNS(Line, "Int", [Intercept])
    VAR x = SELECTEDVALUE('PQDateTable'[MonthCode])
    VAR y = k*x+m
    RETURN y
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joao, your suggested solution works. I'm really grateful. However, I still don't understand why my code behaves the way it does, which is frustrating. If it's obvious for you, please share. But again, thanks a lot for your help.